# Custom BSON Key Value Serializer

Tags: c#, mongodb, bson

I ran into some trouble trying to convert a class to a BSON document.

I have `Custom1` and `Custom2` which should behave a little different. How do I create a custom serializer which "unfold" the `KeyValuePair` so it generates the expected result (See below)? You can see the code example below together with the expected result.

Moreover, I'm using Mongo BSON library for serializing the object.

```
public class UserData
{
    public UserData()
    {
        Id = 100;
        Name = "Superuser";
        Custom1 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("HelloWorld1", 1);
        Custom2 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("HelloWorld2", 2);
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, double> Custom1 { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, double> Custom2 { get; set; }
}
```

Execute test code:

```
var userdata = new UserData();
var doc = userdata.ToBsonDocument();
```

Current result:

```
{
    "Id": 100,
    "Name": "Superuser",
    "Custom1": {
                    "Key": "HelloWorld1",
                    "Value": 1
               },
    "Custom2": {
                    "Key": "HelloWorld2",
                    "Value": 2
               }
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "Id": 100,
    "Name": "Superuser",
    "HelloWorld1": 1,
    "HelloWorld2": 2
}
```

Comment: Kindly post the result which you are getting as well

Comment: @Newton: A current result example is now added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such a complex serialization case you have to implement custom `IBsonSerializer` converter for your class.

Here is the working example:

```
public class UserDataSerializer : SerializerBase<UserData>
{
    public override void Serialize(BsonSerializationContext context, BsonSerializationArgs args, UserData value)
    {
        context.Writer.WriteStartDocument();
        context.Writer.WriteName("Id");
        context.Writer.WriteInt32(value.Id);
        context.Writer.WriteName("Name");
        context.Writer.WriteString(value.Name);

        WriteKeyValue(context.Writer, value.Custom1);
        WriteKeyValue(context.Writer, value.Custom2);

        context.Writer.WriteEndDocument();
    }

    private void WriteKeyValue(IBsonWriter writer, KeyValuePair<string, double> kv)
    {
        writer.WriteName(kv.Key);
        writer.WriteDouble(kv.Value);
    }

    public override UserData Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, BsonDeserializationArgs args)
    {
        //TODO: implement data deserialization using context.Reader
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

To make it work you also need to register our `UserDataSerializer` somehow. `IBsonSerializationProvider` is the easiest way to achieve that.

```
public class UserDataSerializationProvider : IBsonSerializationProvider
{
    public IBsonSerializer GetSerializer(Type type)
    {
        if (type == typeof(UserData)) return new UserDataSerializer();
        return null;
    }
}
```

And finally we can use it.

```
//register our serialization provider
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializationProvider(new UserDataSerializationProvider());

var userdata = new UserData();
var doc = userdata.ToBsonDocument();
```

Here is the result:

```
{ "Id" : 100, "Name" : "Superuser", "HelloWorld1" : 1.0, "HelloWorld2" : 2.0 }
```

You may also want to implement `UserDataSerializer.Deserialize()` method in order to provide the backward conversion. It can be done in the same way using `context.Reader`.

More information about custom serialization process can be found [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/serialization/).

Comment: @SOK Have you tried the example? Do you have any additional questions on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the driver 2.0 or higher,  you could try to make your class into a DynamicObject, like this:

```
public class UserData : DynamicObject
{
 public UserData()
  {
    Id = 100;
    Name = "Superuser";
    Custom1 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("HelloWorld1", 1);
    Custom2 = new KeyValuePair<string, double>("HelloWorld2", 2);
  }

 public id Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public KeyValuePair<string, double> Custom1 { get; set; }
 public KeyValuePair<string, double> Custom2 { get; set; }

 public override bool TryGetMember(
        GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string name = binder.Name;
        result = null;
        if(name.Equals(Custom1.Key)) 
            result = Custom1.Value;
        else if(name.Equals(Custom2.Key))
            result = Custom2.Value;
        return result != null;
    }

  public override bool TrySetMember(
        SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {         
      string name = binder.Name;
      if(name.Equals(Custom1.Key)) 
        Custom1.Value = value;
      else if(name.Equals(Custom2.Key))
        Custom2.Value = value;
      return name.Equals(Custom1.Key) || 
             name.Equals(Custom2.Key);
    }
  }
```

According to the release documentation,  you should then be able to do this:

`var userdata = new UserData();
 var doc = ((dynamic) userdata).ToBsonDocument();`

And get the expected format.

Comment: TryGetMember & TrySetMember are overrides of the default getter and setters?

Comment: @Milton: Thanks for your answer. I really want to avoid reflection. The number of "Custom" values won't change at runtime, and `KeyValuePair` will always have a `Key` and a `Value`so I figured that some sort of custom serializer can be made which just "flattens" the `KeyValuePair`. (I know `.ToBsonDocument` uses reflection but it caches the mapping).